# Proof that "Two elliptic curves which are birationally equivalent are isomorphic".

Tags: elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I am looking for the proof of the following statement:
Two elliptic curves which are birationally equivalent are isomorphic.
Hopefully someone can mention to me some material to prove it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a more general statement: If $C$ and $C'$ are smooth projective curves and $f : C \to C'$ is a rational map, then $f$ is a morphism.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553217/rational-map-on-smooth-projective-curve), or see Hartshorne I.6.